# magento free shipping for specific customer

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

Has anyone already saw or made magento module where you can apply free shipping on specific customer in magento administration. I have already found out that you can apply free shipping on specific customer group but this is not what I need...

Thanks for all your answers and help!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.netismine.com/work/free-shipping-only-for-registered-users

may this will provide path to you

http://magento-rohan.blogspot.in

Comment: this is quite good example but i would have a lot of work to integrate with custom users i want ( i want to check customer who has free shipping...)...